# Mex problem, how to support c99(matlab)

Tags: matlab

I'm using windows os. I want to choose some compilers which can support c99 to mex my cpp files. What should I do? I have installed visual c++ in my os, but I guess it does not support c99

Thanks

Zhong

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20711035/2026975).

Answer (score 1):

Well, comparing the [list of compilers supported by mex](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2010b/index.html) with the [list of compilers supporting C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#Implementations), it looks like the best you can do would probably be Open Watcom or Intel C++, which each have partial support for C99.

If you are able to run on [Linux](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2010b/linux.html) or [Mac OS X](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2010b/maci64.html), you can use GCC, which has better C99 support, but given that you are on Windows, it doesn't appear that Matlab on Windows supports GCC.

Comment: You may find it relatively easy to persuade a Windows installation of Matlab to recognise and use GCC.  Try executing 'mex -setup' and the script should point you to the compiler configuration scripts it uses.

Answer (score 0):

A proposed solution for working with `MinGW` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8553179/1071136).

Transparency: the solution was posted by me.