# Problems cross-compiling a Matlab oct-file using Mingw64 on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, matlab, cross-compiling, mex, mingw-w64

I wrote a C++ application inclunding the external libraries [glpk](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) and [boost](http://www.boost.org/) with a binding to the Matlab API. On Ubuntu compiling in Matlab using mex works fine, the program is running without difficulties.

Now to use the same application on a Windows Platform  I wanted to cross-compile it, using Mingw64. Corresponding to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552580/using-gccmingw-as-matlabs-mex-compiler) it can be done with the following command:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -m64 -shared -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/extern/include" -I"/usr/local/include" -I"/usr/include" -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -o output.mexw64 input.cpp -L"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64/" -lmex -lmx -lmat -leng -L"/usr/lib" -lglpk
```

- Path */usr/local/include* contains the header files for the boost library (header only library)
- Path */usr/include* contains the header files for the glpk library
- Path */usr/lib* contains the source files for the glpk library

But running this command gives me the error that there are `conflicting declarations` of the type:

```
/usr/include/sys/types.h:110:19: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef __ssize_t ssize_t’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/_mingw.h:394:35: error: ‘ssize_t’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef long long int ssize_t’
```

It seems that the path */usr/include* causes problem for the compiler. But it is needed to include the glpk header files. Any ideas to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your glpk headers are in /usr/include, chances are you didn't compile the library for Windows. You should cross-compile all libraries for the target platform (and install them in /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32 (if I deduce your installation details correctly).

One big gotcha you're not going to be able to solve: your Matlab is Linux, and doesn't contain any Windows linkable libraries, so you're out of luck anyways.

Comment: I've now installed [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) on a windows machine to use the Matlab's dll's. But now I get errors of the form: `error: '::strtold' has not been declared`

Comment: You don't need Cygwin to run Matlab nor MinGW binaries. The Microsoft C runtime does not have `strtold`.