# how to do static linking of libwinpthread-1.dll in mingw?

Tags: c++, mingw, static-linking

I use mingw from here: `http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.7.2/32-bit/threads-posix/sjlj/x32-4.7.2-release-posix-sjlj-rev2.7z/download`

And I've sucessfully managed to link statically `libstdc++-6.dll` and `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll` by using `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` parameters, but I cannot find a command for doing the same with `libwinpthread-1.dll`.

Comment: Just for the sake of technical clarity, if you're statically linking, you're not linking to the DLL. The libraries `libgcc` and `libstdc++` have static and non-static (DLL) versions, and if you statically link, you're not linking to the DLLs. You want to statically link to the `pthreads` library, not to `libwinpthread-1.dll` (since you can't statically link to a dynamic library... that defeats the purpose of a dynamic library).

Comment: I get: `c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-static-pthreads'` , the same with `winpthreads`

Comment: Quick gotcha: the libwinpthread-1.dll that comes with mingw is not the same as the one(s) floating round on the internet. Using the wrong one will result in an infinitely recursive DLL call (according to Dependency walker) followed by a stack overflow.

Comment: Just link with `-l:libwinpthread.a`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should probably check command line options documentation for GCC.

These's no '-static-something' command, only standard libraries (libgcc and libstdc++) can be set to static linking with one command. For other libraries, you first switch to static linking with "-static" and then list the libraries to include with separate commands, ie "-lpthread".

Comment: I found that this problem surfaced when I switched from using a version of mingw I downloaded to the version installed by apt-get on Ubuntu.  The apt-get version is older but I think the problem arises from a different configuration used to build the mingw tool set. Adding "-static -lpthread" fixed the problem.

Comment: `libgcc` is no standard library. See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Libgcc.html)

Comment: please tell me how i can use -static and then still make my program rely on the thread dll if you can. (i'm pretty sure by putting -static all you're doing is making it link everything static. you don't need to put anymore -l libraries after it. unless you can tell me how to make it rely on a dll afterwards, this answer is just incorrect)

Answer (score 63):

If your toolchain includes the static winpthreads, adding the option

```
-static
```

Will pull in static versions of all libraries it can.

Alternatively, you can remove libwinpthread.dll.a and the DLL itself from the toolchain directories. This might mess up programs linking with libstdc++ and libgcc  DLLs though, so be careful.

A third option is to use `-Wl,-Bdynamic` and `-Wl,-Bstatic` to select which version you want linked in (which is what `-static` internally does when ld is called). An example:

```
gcc -o someexec someobject.o -Wl,-Bdynamic -lsomelibIwantshared -Wl,-Bstatic -lsomelibIwantstatic
```

If you run your link command with `-v` added, you should see these options appearing in the ld/collect2 invocation when you use `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++`.

Answer (score 37):

Try this:

```
-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++ -lpthread -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

Notice the `-lstdc++` before `-lpthread`. It worked for me.

Make sure to add this to the very end of your `g++` command line.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, unfortunately, unless I remove the trailing `-Wl,-Bdynamic` (which is nonsense).

Comment: @rr- Try use gcc -v to print out verbose information, send it to me. And I will look into it.

Comment: I think I get it... I need `libwinpthread-1.dll` only if I compile with static `libstdc++`, meaning in my environment (arch and official repositories) static version of libstdc++ depends on shared winpthread. To get around this I probably need to compile mingw-w64 myself.

Comment: @rr- I am glad you have figured it out. Please tell me if you get it solved. (Also, I am just using ArchLinux now without any problem.)

Comment: @rr- I think you should add your comment as an answer. I wasted part of the afternoon figuring this out.

Comment: I don't know why the "-lstdc++" is important, as I would guess "-static-libstdc++" does the same. But without it, this doesn't work oddly enough.

Comment: Thank you!! This answer unstuck me for a ton of linking stuff.

Answer (score 27):

To statically link **winpthread** even if threading isn't used in the program, pass the `-Bstatic` and `--whole-archive` parameters to the linker:

```
g++ -o hello.exe hello.cpp -Wl,-Bstatic,--whole-archive -lwinpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

Note the following:

- The "whole archive" option should be disabled immediately afterwards.
- You don't need to do this hack if your program actually uses symbols from the library (i.e. you use `<thread>` from C++11), in which case the library won't get dropped when you statically link it.
- This hack is intended for MinGW-w64, to fix the *libwinpthread-1.dll* dependencies.

Comment: It's a great idea but there is at least one disadvantage. The win32 ressources of the main `exe` are replaced by the resources of `libwinpthread-1.dll` (look at the `exe` properties with the file explorer; the entries concern `libwinpthread-1.dll` instead of `hello.exe`).

Comment: Worked for me, just needed `-Bdynamic` alongside `--no-whole-archive`, because I don't have a way to append this whole bit to the very end of my command (limitations of the toolchain), and the end target is a shared lib.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone working in CMake, this solution is readily implemented in your CMakeLists.txt file as follows...

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -static")
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work just by using `-static` in linker flags / `LDFLAGS`.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently, CMake does some weird stuff with how the `-Wl` compiler flags are handled, making the `-Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++ -lwinpthread -Wl,-Bdynamic` solution not work, with only two other options seemingly left: the bad compiler flag `-static` and the ugly compiler flag `-Wl,--whole-archive`.

Meanwhile, the good option that actually works in CMake, yet seems rather undocumented, is to directly use the linker flags. Hence, in CMake, this seems to be the best way to statically link to all the mingw-w64 C++ dependencies:

```
target_link_libraries (MyVeryAwesomeApp -static gcc stdc++ winpthread -dynamic)
```

It should be noted that even if there isn't a library explicitly following `-dynamic`, it should still be applied in order to ensure that the standard, implicitly linked libraries get linked correctly.

Comment: `-static -dynamic` will statically link everything putting -dynamic at the end doesn't do anything. infact, putting `-static -dynamicdgdf` works. i can't find documentation on the `-dynamic` option only the `-static` option. all you're doing is `-static` with unneeded extras. without the extra options after `-static` the exe is actually smaller too

Comment: @Puddle If the executable is smaller when missing the extra options after `-static`, care to explain as to how exactly that happens, if, as You claim, that makes gcc statically link everything? I think that an experiment involving an attempt to run such a smaller executable on a Windows instance that does not have the g++ toolchain installed, without the gcc, stdc++ and winpthread dlls in the same directory, would explain a lot. To my understanding, what the `-static` and `-dynamic` options do in `target_link_libraries` closely mirrors the behavior of `-Bstatic` and `-Bdynamic` without CMake.

Comment: Thanks I've been running into this issue when trying to set up a development environment for SDL2 with OpenGL.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, COM libraries followed by `-dynamic` do not require wine exports anymore, that's great.

Answer (score 1):

I circumvented this problem by using win32 variant of the mingw toolchain instead of the posix variant. With the win32 variant, `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` is sufficient for an independent build.

Comment: how do you select win32 variant?

Comment: On Ubuntu, mingw comes with two compilers `i686-w64-mingw32-g++-posix` and `i686-w64-mingw32-g++-win32`. In my build environment, I specified `CXX=/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++-win32`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using toolchains from  MSys2 (tested with gcc version 12) ,the only way to use winpthread statically is standard -static (forces all library to be static) or simply delete/rename the libwinpthread.dll.a && libpthread.dll.a imp libs.
Other methods like "Bstatic", "-l:libwinpthread.a" will no longer work (due to dependency hell, especially in CMake). The one with whole archive still works but it overrides the program properties.
You may also want static link libgcc and libstdc++ if the dependency comes from them.

Answer (score -1):

Just link with `-l:libwinpthread.a`

Answer (score -2):

Just add `-static` to your `CFLAGS`.

For example: `./configure CFLAGS="-static"`.

This will link all static libraries to your executable file.