# MinGW .exe requires a few gcc dll's regardless of the code?

Tags: c++, dll, mingw

When compiling with MinGW, I have to copy over certain dll files from the MinGW bin directory before the exe will run (Even when using "-static" and/or "-static-libstdc++".)
How do I change that? Is there a special build of MinGW that I have to use? Ultimately I want to be able to run the program with nothing but the exe in the directory (and no windows environment variables set.) These File's are:

- libstdc++-6.dll
- libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
- libwinpthread-1.dll

And here is the complete list of step's I fallow:

1. Open Up Code::Blocks
2. Select "File->New->Project->Console"
3. Fill out the project settings for project "Hello World"
4. Right click Project->Build Options...->Hello World (Root target)->Other Options
5. Enter "-static" (or "-static-libstdc++") under the already set "-fexceptions"
6. CTRL-F9 : Build Project (Without executing)
7. Navigate to, in Windows Explorer, and run the built "Hello World.exe" file.
8. Click "OK" when a message pop's up saying "Error: libstdc++-6.dll is missing from your computer."
9. Copy "libstdc++-6.dll" from the /MinGW/bin/ directory, into the "Hello World.exe" directory.
10. Run "Hello World.exe"
11. Click "OK" for the message saying "Error: libgcc_s_seh-1.dll is missing from your computer."
12. Copy "libgcc_s_seh-1.dll" into the "Hello World.exe" directory.
13. Repeat and end up copying "libwinpthread-1.dll" over aswell.
14. View the message

    ```
    Hello World!
    ```

**Edit:**
My command line is:

```
g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -g -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -L. -c "C:\Users\______\Desktop\Hello World\main.cpp" -o obj\Debug\main.o
g++.exe -o "bin\Debug\Hello World.exe" obj\Debug\main.o
```

With all the dll files mentioned above required. And, just to be safe, the code is:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do is bundle everything into a single relocatable executable.

Comment: I would build it outside of code blocks.  You need to see your build command.

Comment: Any chance that you are building inside the NSYS2 environment with the `msys/gcc` compiler? Because if that's the case you should be using the mingw64 terminal and using the `mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` compiler.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**Your commands are wrong !**

Go to the directory where your *main.cpp* file is, and try the following.

```
g++.exe -Wall -c -g main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
g++.exe -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o "bin\Debug\Hello World.exe" obj\Debug\main.o
```

then you'll no longer need to copy the DLLs (for your Hello World program).

**Other notes:**

The MinGW installation instructions recommends setting

```
c:\minGW;c:\MinGW\bin;
```

to the PATH environment variable.

Normally the

```
-static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

linker options should work (try all 3 of them at once). But not for `libwinpthread-1.dll`.

Also, try to `clean` before recompiling.

There's no "-static-something" command.

Only standard libraries *libgcc* and *libstdc++* can be set to static linking.

For other libraries, you first switch to static linking with "-static" and then list the libraries to include with separate commands, i.e. "-lpthread".

**Cmake users should try adding:**

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lwsock32 -lws2_32 ${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES}")

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-Bstatic,--whole-archive -lwinpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive")
```

**libraries **

Note that if you are building your own cpp libraries to use/link against (ex: libXX.a files), they must be compiled with the same -static-* options as you use for your main program, otherwise it will crash.

Comment: Because he probably wants to distribute the app, and doesn't want clients to have to install MinGW or modify environment variables

Comment: @Praetorian : This is a development environment. If the OP wants to give to his customers, he has to pack all necessary dll's with the setup file anyway. But it looks like it's only `Hello World` tests.  Therefore, it would be pretty stupid not to have the required files in a folder where they can be found. For a downvote that's pretty vague.

Comment: *Ultimately I want to be able to run the program with nothing but the exe in the directory* ... it seems not packaging the DLLs is exactly what he wants to do. Which should be possible if there are static library versions of all the runtime libraries.

Comment: For some reason, the three command line options didn't change anything. (made an edit) Also, Praetorian, is right. I could package the dlls with the exe (if I did), or add the env variable to make it work on **my** machine, but it seems excessive with a console application that print's "Hello World!" to require 3 dll files. It, to me, look's like unnecessary bulk that is also going to be tagging along in other, more advanced, applications I might write. On-top of that, looking at other more advanced applications, the dlls included are library's that the developer created or something similar.

Comment: A pitfall to watch out for: if your app links to a DLL (e.g. wxbase) and that DLL dynamically links to libstdc++ then you're out of luck (and it will be confusing why adding `-static-libstdc++` doesn't remove libstdc++ from the dependencies until you realize what is going on!)

Comment: For **libwinpthread-1.dll** the following linker trick can be used `-Wl,-Bstatic,--whole-archive -lwinpthread` as detailed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43402308/7023624). This will link **winpthread** statically without having to resort to `-static`.

Comment: I assume `CMAKE_CSS_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` was intended to be `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`?

Comment: `CMAKE_CSS_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` was added by @bremen_matt. I don't know right or wrong!

Comment: Did you delete it?  It was a good command just had a typo.  Please don't delete good code!  I would have fixed it myself, but minor changes are generally rejected in favor of comments.  Resubmitted with typo corrected.

Comment: Maybe @bremen_matt looks at it ;-)

Comment: Sorry. I don't have time to look into this. I thought the code was right. But if the original poster disagrees, then I feel obliged to remove the code, particularly since I don't have time to investigate further.

Answer (score 12):

`-static-libgcc` may be a bad idea if exceptions are used. [link options documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) states that

> There are several situations in which an application should use the
>   shared libgcc instead of the static version. The most common of these
>   is when the application wishes to throw and catch exceptions across
>   different shared libraries. In that case, each of the libraries as
>   well as the application itself should use the shared libgcc.

Comment: Almost no windows apps do this AFAICT...

Answer (score 2):

The comments to the answer above contain the full solution, so I would like to merely add the CodeBlocks perspective. I verified it on Windows7 x64 with CodeBlocks16 and MinGW-W64 8.1.0 ''i686-posix-dwarf''.

This solves the OPs question

- Create new project and name it "Hello World"
- accept all defaults in the wizard
- select Project/BuildOptions/ and select "Hello World". Out edits will be valid for both Debug and Release
- add the following at "Other linker option" in the "Linker" Tab

  ```
  -static
  -static-libgcc
  -static-strc++
  -lwinpthread
  ```
- On the Toolbar select "Debug" and press Build (the yellow gear icon)
- Press the green run icon and confirm that the build was ok

Testing

- open a terminal window and go to the HelloWorld\bin\debug folder
- start hello world there.
- Confirm it works without asking for any DLLs.

You could also start it from an explorer window and confirm that it also does not ask for DLLs.

*Note: On my Win7x64 system when starting the HelloWorld.exe from the explorer adding the "-lwinpthread" line causes CodeBlocks to ignore the setting in "Projects/Properties/Tab_BuildTargets/ "Pause when execution ends". So the "Hello World" output is hardly visible because the window immediately closes after execution (mabye someone knows why)*

Note that if you do **not** have the **winpthread.dll not found** problem of the OP then you likely do not use a MinGW-W64 compiler with a 'posix' thread model. Both Code blocks MinGW-W64-bundled install packages use such versions. For CB20.03 the relevant downloads from [MinGW-W64 download page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/) would be

- 32bit: 8.1.0 ''i686-posix-dwarf''
- 64bit: 8.1.0 ''x86_64-posix-seh''

For example if I set setup compilers with Codeblocks direcly and chose the 32-bit compiler package ''i686-win32-dwarf'', only the first 2 DLLs would go missing. In that case the fix is to set the linker options only to

```
  -static-libgcc
  -static-strc++
```