# configure: error: unrecognized option: -static-libgcc

Tags: c, mingw, static-linking, configure, zbar

I'm trying to compile zbar-0.10 to be statically linked to the MinGW dependencies, so it doesn't require `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll`, `libwinpthread-1.dll`, and `libstdc++-6.dll`.

Following the accepted answer from [MinGW .exe requires a few gcc dll's regardless of the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138635/mingw-exe-requires-a-few-gcc-dlls-regardless-of-the-code), I tried adding `-static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` to my `./configure` script parameters:

```
./configure -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static -lpthread --without-qt --without-gtk --without-python --without-imagemagick
```

But I got this error:

```
configure: error: unrecognized option: -static-libgcc
```

What are the correct parameters to pass to the configure script so the MinGW dependencies are statically linked to ZBar?

Comment: Maybe your MinGW version does not support it? Are you using libtool? if yes, [this man](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Sneak_GCC_Switches_Past_Libtool) should help.

Answer (score 0):

The option `-static` is enough for what you want achieve when you use MinGW toolchain.