# What do I have to do next to get my g++ compiled executable to run on other windows machines?

Tags: compilation, g++, exe, executable

So, I've been looking and looking and looking. It's odd to me that is not something programmers like to readily answer. I don't understand why. What are they afraid of? Is it a pride thing, that we should somehow be able to guess at it ourselves, like pull it out of the dark somehow like they did at one time maybe? I don't get it.

I see people asking this question all over the internet, and every single time, it never fails, nobody actually answers the question. They just respond by asking things like "what's the error" all of the time.

What do you think the error is? It's that the person hasn't yet done the extra steps to make their executable run on other windows machines.

My issue:
I'm running g++ from the command prompt. I installed cygwin and mingw, and then I added the bin folder of the one I want to use to my path variable in windows. I do NOT include both bin folders. Only the one the that I am using at the time. I've been alternating between the two in an effort to figure out how I'm supposed to make my small simple C++ program run on another windows machine. One of the forums, some post said that he uses mingw, presumably to avoid the problem of needing cygwin dll's . . . or something . . . I didn't quite understand.

Quick intro: 
The program is simply a small program created from another similar program in a textbook to make the computer guess a number I have picked 1 through 100. I wanted to compile, and then put that executable on my sister or mom's computer and let them play so they can say, "How cool, you created that?"

I mean, at some point, I want to actually learn how to do this. Maybe I'm just a moron, but it just seems natural to me that at some point people want their executables to work on other machines. Seems like a simple question that every programmer must have at one point wondered about, but nobody seems to realize in all of these people asking this question that they simply need to know what the next step is.

So of course, I'm running into the issue that they don't have the dll's that are provided by mingw and cygwin. Naturally, this is because most Windows machines are not going to have those dll's.

So, what do I need to do to make my executable capable of running on other windows machines? Right now, I'm just talking about Windows 10. I use Windows 10 pro, latest build as of June 2018, and they use Windows 10 Home, probably the latest build since they do automatic updates. (Not sure if the normally forced install of the latest build has occurred, but I think it has.)

So, to anyone who read that and answers, thank you.

Comment: Just a gentle hint: that entire first paragraph is a rant, and so is 50% of the rest of the question, you should consider removing it. And, your question is an actual wall of text, probably nobody isn't going to read it (keyword TL;DR ).  May I suggest you try to make the question a bit shorter? That in my experience improves your chance of getting a competent answer more quickly!

Comment: I might have to ask it again some other time. I just don't understand why people can't just be direct. If I knew an answer to something, I would just tell people the answer.

Comment: What I was trying to convey is that, knowing SO a bit, 90% of the readers don't make it past the first paragraph... What works best here is a short, dry, and laserlike to the point style. That being said, I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138635/mingw-exe-requires-a-few-gcc-dlls-regardless-of-the-code could help you, but in order to get programming and actually enjoying the experience, have you considered using the free https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/ VS Community version?

Comment: having the same issue here