# How to compile ffmpeg for Windows statically with MSYS2 environment?

Tags: ffmpeg, mingw, static-linking, mingw-w64, msys2

I want to build myself standalone statically linked ffmpeg binaries for Windows from official git source code with MSYS2 environment tools. But every time I get .exe file dynamically linked to mingw libraries that crashes with "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)" error even if I put required libbz2-1.dll, libiconv-2.dll and libwinpthread-1.dll libraries in it's folder.

I'm running MSYS2 environment with

```
msys2_shell.cmd -mingw64
```

line, and use mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc 8.2.1+20181214-1 compiler package. Then I run ./configure with

```
./configure --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-shared --enable-static
```

line - the best options I have googled at all my efforts. Then proceed with general

```
make
make install
```

sequence.

As a result, I get binaries that run smoothly in MSYS2 environment itself, but when I run it from host Windows explorer or cmd, first of all it ask for libbz2-1.dll, libiconv-2.dll and libwinpthread-1.dll libraries and when I put them in binaries' folder, they crash with "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)" error.

I've asked about this case at official https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=6439 forum but still have no response for already 5 days.

Regarding dynamic linking libraries somehow I got bandaid solution with removing *.dll.a files from mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib folder. But it looks not very clean for me. I wish to know if it is possible to do static linkage with some compiler/make/linker parameters or with editing ./configure or Makefile files somehow?

Also 0xc000007b error still remaining.

I've managed to have desired result with media-autobuild_suite based on the same MSYS2 environment, so I know it is possible to do this somehow. But I'm very new to all this *nix things so don't understand it's bash script at all, not to mention it is pretty sophisticated by itself. The only thing I see it's producing correct ffmpeg executables running under native Windows environment not requiring dlls listed above.

According to all guides in internet I found at the moment, I should get standalone Windows executables with this toolset, but it just don't work and I'm stuck. Please, help.

Comment: Do you need a fully static solution where the only DLLs your executables depend on are those that come with Windows?  Or would you be OK with having some DLLs copied to the same folder as the executables like you have been doing?

Comment: @DavidGrayson yes, I aim for fully static solution where the only DLLs my executables depend on are those that come with Windows.

Comment: having the same issue, did you figured it out?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems. To solve it, I try to disable all external libraries.

My configuration:

```
--enable-static --enable-gpl --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect
```

After compiling, I copy the **libwinpthread-1.dll** from **/mingw64/bin** to the binaries' folder. (you can use `ldd ffmpeg.exe` to print shared library dependencies)

ffmpeg.exe and ffprobe.exe can run successfully.

using ffmpeg-4.4 & msys2-x86_64-20210419

Answer (score 0):

`./configure --extra-ldflags=-static`

Helps https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MinGW (msys2 at the bottom) see also [MinGW .exe requires a few gcc dll's regardless of the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138635/mingw-exe-requires-a-few-gcc-dlls-regardless-of-the-code)