# Eliminate dependency on MinGW-specific DLLs when compiling dynamic library

Tags: c, dll, static-linking, mingw-w64, msys2

I am using msys2 to compile a library that uses autotools as the build system. The end result is a DLL. This DLL ends up referring to the following other DLLs that come with msys2:

- `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll`
- `libstdc++-6.dll`
- `libwinpthread-1.dll`

**How can I link these statically and eliminate these dependencies?**

There are other questions dealing with this ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138635/mingw-exe-requires-a-few-gcc-dlls-regardless-of-the-code)) and the solutions suggest using the options `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++`. These work when linking an `.exe`, but they do not seem to work when linking a `.dll`.

I set the following variables before running `./configure` (and checked the output to verify that these compiler options are really being used), but Dependency Walker still shows a dependency on `libstdc++-6.dll`, just as before.

```
export CFLAGS="-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" CXXFLAGS="-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" LDFLAGS="-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++"
```

(I assume these must only go in LDFLAGS, but since I don't have a full understanding, I also added them in CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS.)

Is there a way to get rid of these dependencies when linking a DLL, not an EXE?

The library is written in a mix of C and C++ and has a C API.

Answer (score 2):

Try just using the `-static` option in LDFLAGs.  I tested it just now in MSYS2 and it worked for me.

Comment: Did you test it when creating a DLL or an EXE? It appears to prevent the creation of a DLL.

Comment: You're right, it works on a minimal example. I need to figure out why it does not work when compiling this library.

Comment: Note that when using `-static` you also need to link with the dependancies of the dependancies, and with their dependancies and so on.

If the libraries come with `.pc` files this can be solved by linking with the output of `pkg-config --static --libs <libraries>`

Comment: I don't think so.  We are still making a DLL, not a static library (.a), and DLLs include references to the DLLs they depend on.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Funny thing about Windows is that it is possible to make a DLL that statically links with its dependancies. So `-static` can be combined with `-o <dllname> -Wl,--out-implib,<dllname>.a` which you can then combine with `$(pkg-config --static --libs <libraries>)` as mentioned earlier.

Comment: In your example, you shouldn't need to use `--static` but I guess it depends on whether the authors of the .pc file did a good job in defining the .pc file.  DLLs do not depend on .a files after they have been created because DLLs are a thing that the OS knows how to run, and .a is a compiler file format.  If you can make a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) or a blog post or something that demonstrates your point using a precise sequence of MSYS2 shell commands, we could discuss it there, instead of cluttering up this question.