# The code executable cannot continue: libgcc_s_seh-1.dll was not found

Tags: qt, dll

I have a problem that I cannot solve, When I run the executable of my program it gives me the following error:

```
The code executable cannot continue because libgcc_s_seh-1.dll was not found. To fix the problem, try reinstalling the program
```

I tried to manually copy and paste the file (libgcc_s_seh-1.dll) into the folder where I keep the executable but I get the following error:

```
The application could not be started correctly (0xc000007b)
```

Additional information:

- I use windows 10 64 bit
- I Use mingw81_64
- I use version 6.1.2 of Qt

What can I solve the problem?

Comment: how did you deploy it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MinGW .exe requires a few gcc dll's regardless of the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138635/mingw-exe-requires-a-few-gcc-dlls-regardless-of-the-code)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you double-clicked in exe file that provides after building in release mode :
For Deploy and create Exe output with QT in windows you should follow this way:

1. put your compiler path in your system path. now you use mingw81_64 you should set it. something like  `Qt/tools/mingw81_64/bin`
2. copy exe file that provides after building in release mode in one folder and run mingw81_64 cmd (it has separate cmd)
   and cd to that folder path
3. `windeployqt  app.exe`

**This command will get all dll needs for your app and your exe will work .**

if you use qml

```
windeployqt --qmldir (the path of its directory ) app.exe
```

and also see these youtube videos for more info:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdSTgR0xJco

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCXAgB6y8eA

Comment: Grazie ho risolto

Comment: Hi, I just have the same problem, but I couldn't get what you mean in "2. Copy exe..."  , where's the separate cmd?

Comment: @user174174 when you build your project in release mode in build path it create exe file but that wasn't exe that could run for users because it needs dll. You should copy that exe in one folder and then open cmd of mingw , not  usual cmd.  For  more details  I recommend you watch YouTube movies it do all Steps and you can see what will happen

Comment: @Parisa.H.R thanks a lot, worked even on another machine. Upvoting your answer! Btw, the size is huge, the release build is 30KB but including dlls and other stuff it's 53MB! Any workarounds for that?

Comment: Yeah,  it happens and this relates to your code. I don't know way for decreased the size of it. I think it's another question,  @user174174

Answer (score 0):

For specific error of `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll was not found`, please try to copy libgcc_s_seh-1.dll, libstdc++-6.dll, libwinpthread-1.dll into your compiler path like Qt/tools/mingw81_64/bin.

Answer (score 0):

You should copy libgcc_s_seh-1.dll, libstdc++-6.dll, libwinpthread-1.dll into your exefile path after executing windeployqt.exe with all files are in correct version.

Comment: What do you mean by "with all files are in correct version."? Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

This probably means the program's libraries have been gathered incorrectly. If you didn't build the program yourself, you might need to ask the person who did that to fix it.

I got this error when I had run windeployqt without my qt environment set up properly (I just ran it using a command inside a batch file, launched straight from Windows Explorer).

In order for it to work for me, I needed to run windeployqt from inside a "Qt" command prompt.

This is provided as part of the Qt install.
When I search for "Qt", they show up in my Start Menu like this:
[image: Qt Command promts in the Windows Start Menu]

When you launch the command prompt, it will say `Setting up environment for Qt usage...`

Then, inside that prompt, change directory to the location where your executable was built and run windeployqt:

```
cd C:\path\to\your\program\release
windeployqt <name-of-your-program>.exe
```

You should then be able to launch the exe file.