# Does MATLAB support GCC as a compiler for MEX files? Why isnt it listed on their page?

Tags: matlab, compiler-construction, compilation, mex

I am a total noob when it comes to compiling MEX files for MATLAB. I am thoroughly confused by the different versions of things, compilers, MATLAB versions, etc.

I have MATLAB 2013a, 64-bit, on a Windows-7 machine. I would like to add a C/C++ compiler to it, so that I can compile MEX files. This [page here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013a/) does not list the GCC compiler as a possible use.

However, for many files on the matlab exchange, they use GCC>= 4.2 apparently, for compiling MEX files.

So I am confused... all I want to do is run a MEX file, and install a compiler... does GCC work? If so why isnt it listed on the MATLAB page? Where do I start?...

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using GCC(minGW) as Matlab's MEX compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552580/using-gccmingw-as-matlabs-mex-compiler)

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny I saw that post, however this is slightly different.

Comment: You can use the free Windows SDK.  GCC is not needed.

Comment: For 64-bit Windows installations, the easiest method to get started with MEX is to install Visual Studio *Professional* (pick a version supported by your MATLAB version, VS2010 or VS2012 are good choices). Of course that is not a free product. The express version of Visual Studio (which is available for free) does not include the 64-bit C/C++ compilers. So you will need to download the free Windows SDK as well. Here are some instructions you could follow: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96611, http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101105