# Matlab 2015a set mingw64 as mex compiler

Tags: matlab, mex, mingw-w64

I have Matlab2015a 64bit running on Win7 and I want to use Mingw-w64 compiler for mex files but the command *

```
mex -setup
```

says

> MEX configured to use 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 (C)' for C language
>   compilation.

I have installed Mingw-w6 compiler in

> C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-4.9.2-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev4\mingw64\bin

I even had a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809317/linker-error-compiling-mex-with-mingw-w64), but I could'n solve it.

How can I switch to Mingw gcc compiler?

Comment: The only supported compilers are these: https://uk.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2015a/index.html

Comment: It seems it is supported only from 2015b. Thanks

Comment: Then you can not use it unless you update your Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see which compilers are supported by your MATLAB version and OS go to

```
mathworks.com/support/compilers/VERSION/index.html
```

where VERSION is your version. i.e.

[`mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2015a/index.html`](http://uk.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2015a/index.html)

If a compiler is not there, then you can not use it. In your case, its not there.