# Use GCC as the Default MEX Compiler for MATLAB 2014a on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine

Tags: c, windows, matlab, gcc, mex

I am looking for a simple way to compile Unix MEX files on a Windows 7 computer.

The MEX files compile smoothly in MATLAB 2014a on Mac OS X 10.9 (using "XCode with Clang" as the compiler). Some of the people that I work with, however, are having trouble compiling them in Windows 7 using the C compiler from the Windows 7.1 SDK.

I understand that I might be able to avoid these errors if I use GCC to compile MEX files in MATLAB. I am wondering if anyone knows how. I am happy to download and edit whatever files are necessary so that I can a) compile MEX files within MATLAB by using the "MEX" command and b) guarantee that "-I" and "-L" instructions will also passed to the MEX compiler.

Note, my issue is very similar [to this post from 2+ years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552580/using-gccmingw-as-matlabs-mex-compiler). That said, I have put up a new post since a) MATLAB/MinGW/MEX have all had significant updates since then (not even sure if MinGW is the easiest way out of this mess); b) there is a 64 bit thing (not sure if it's a problem) and c) the "-I" and "-L" options are important.

Comment: ok, but did you try any of the suggested solutions in that question? If so what was the problem?

Comment: @Amro Yes! I tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14238515/568249) solution first, but actually ended up ruining the MATLAB MEX setup installation (I suspect because gnumex is simply too old). I also tried to adapt [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12450944/568249) but could not find the mexopts.bat file in the directory. I thought it was worth asking a new question since the setup is different in multiple ways / enough time had passed for there to be new solutions.

Comment: ok I posted some instructions for MinGW-w64. But using the free Windows SDK is just as easy (perhaps even easier because `mex -setup` can detect it out of the box).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Start by downloading MinGW-w64 compiler toolchain. We'll be using the x64 version. Here's the link to the [latest binaries](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.9.1/threads-posix/seh/x86_64-4.9.1-release-posix-seh-rt_v3-rev1.7z/download) as of this moment (GNU GCC 4.9.1).
- Extract the 7z archive to some location (preferably without spaces), say `C:\MinGW-w64\mingw64`.
- Add the `bin` folder to your PATH environment variable, so something like `set PATH=C:\MinGW-w64\mingw64\bin;%PATH%` but do it system-wide.
- Create the following file (feel free to add compiler switches like `-std=c++11` if you want C++11 support):

  #### mexopts_mingw64.bat

  ```
  @echo off

  set MATLAB=%MATLAB%
  set MW_TARGET_ARCH=win64
  set MINGWROOT=C:\MinGW-w64\mingw64
  set PATH=%MINGWROOT%\bin;%PATH%

  set COMPILER=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
  set COMPFLAGS=-c -m64 -mwin32 -mdll -Wall -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE
  set OPTIMFLAGS=-DNDEBUG -O2
  set DEBUGFLAGS=-g
  set NAME_OBJECT=-o

  set LINKER=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
  set LIBLOC=%MATLAB%\extern\lib\%MW_TARGET_ARCH%\microsoft
  set LINKFLAGS=-shared -L"%LIBLOC%" -L"%MATLAB%\bin\%MW_TARGET_ARCH%"
  set LINKFLAGSPOST=-lmx -lmex -lmat
  set LINKOPTIMFLAGS=-O2
  set LINKDEBUGFLAGS=-g
  set LINK_FILE=
  set LINK_LIB=
  set NAME_OUTPUT=-o "%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%%MEX_EXT%"

  set RC_COMPILER=
  set RC_LINKER=
  ```
- Now we use it to compile a sample MEX-file:

  ```
  >> mex -f mexopts_mingw64.bat -v -largeArrayDims "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\examples\mex\yprime.c"

  >> yprime(1,1:4)
  ans =
      2.0000    8.9685    4.0000   -1.0947
  ```

Note: If you are compiling C++ code and you want to distribute the binaries to other people, you might need to also include a couple of DLL files from MinGW which will be dependencies for the compiled MEX-file (stuff like libstdc++). Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) tool to list them all.

Comment: note: `mexopts.bat` files were deprecated starting with R2014a, and are expected to be removed in future versions in favor of XML configuration files.

Comment: Thank you so much. This setup compiles 'yprime.c' just fine. However, it does not compile the C code that I had previously (which compiles fine in UNIX / Mac OS X). I guess I just want to make sure that compiling using gcc/MinGW dos not always work (to rule out silly mistakes).

Comment: @BerkU.: it should compile fine assuming you're only using standard C/C++ (some POSIX stuff is not portable to Windows, in which case you'll have to find the Win32 equivalent and use `#if/#else` macros around platform-specific functionality)