# Header file not found even though it is in a directory specified by -I

Tags: c++, matlab, makefile, simulink

I am trying to compile a Simulink S-function using Mingw.

My Makefile contains the following:

```
MINGWPATH=D:/Mingw
MATLABROOT=C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2014b
CC=$(MINGWPATH)/bin/gcc 
MEXFLAG=-shared -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I$(MATLABROOT)\simulink\include -I$(MATLABROOT)\extern\include -Wl,--export-all-symbols $(LIBS) $(MEXSRC) -o $(MEXTGT).mexw64

LIBS= -L$(MATLABROOT)/bin/win64 -L$(MATLABROOT)/extern/lib/win64/microsoft -lmex -lmx -lmwlapack -lmwblas -leng

MEXTGT=SFCN_Block
MEXSRC=SFCN_Block.cpp
all:$(MEXTGT)

$(MEXTGT): $(MEXSRC)
    $(CC) $(MEXFLAG) -ladvapi32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lkernel32 -lmingwex
```

The `SFCN_Block.cpp` file contains an `#include 'simstruc.h'` and `simstruc.h` *is* in `C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2014b\simulink\include`.

But I get the following error:

```
SFCN_Block.cpp:12:22: fatal error: simstruc.h: No such file or directory
 #include "simstruc.h"
                      ^
```

How can it possibly go wrong?

(My Matlab version is R2014b (64 bits) under Windows 7, and I am trying to compile using Mingw. My Makefile is based on the accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552580/using-gcc-mingw-as-matlabs-mex-compiler/9451392#9451392)).

Comment: That file is where under the `C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2014b` directory?

Comment: In this directory exactly, not in a subdirectory.

Comment: You don't use that directory exactly as a `-I` argument. You use two subdirectories of it.

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes: `simstruc.h` is in `C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2014b\simulink\include`. I edited my question to fix this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the first lines of the Makefile to:

```
MINGWPATH=D:/Mingw
MATLABROOT="C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b"
SIMULINK_INCLUDE_PATH=$(MATLABROOT)/simulink/include
MATLAB_EXTERN_INCLUDE_PATH=$(MATLABROOT)/extern/include
CC=$(MINGWPATH)/bin/gcc 
MEXFLAG=-shared -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -IBlocks -IDesignPatterns -ILogging -I$(SIMULINK_INCLUDE_PATH) -I$(MATLAB_EXTERN_INCLUDE_PATH) -Wl,--export-all-symbols $(LIBS) $(MEXSRC) -o $(MEXTGT).mexw64
```

solves the `No such file or directory` error. Can anyone explain why?

Now I get the following error:

`C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b/bin/win64/libmex.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized`

but it is an other question.

Comment: Did you fix the libmex.dll: file not recognized problem? Could you please share your solution? I appreciate it!

Comment: Too late, but maybe the problem might be inconsistency and forward/back slashes in path?