# mex -setup : No supported compiler or SDK was found

Tags: spring, matlab, visual-studio-2013, sdk, installation

I have installed windows7 on my machine today and I then visual studio 2013 and MATLABR2015A on it. I'm sure that these two can be integrated with each other and have tried it many many times.

I even have developed my algorithm with the same integration. But this time, when I want to use it I get the error:

```
mex -setup
Error using mex
No supported compiler or SDK was found. For options, visit  http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2015a/win64.html.
```

I have no idea how to solve this error and just want to run my algorithm on a computer with higher configuration.

[image]

Comment: I'm not a fan of Visual Studio, but recently I wrote an answer for setting up `Mingw` for  `mex` in Matlab for `Windows 7`. You can find my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552580/using-gcc-mingw-as-matlabs-mex-compiler/41307093#41307093).